# How can I get the solution to a certain kind of system of PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations

`DSolve` seems to have issues with the following form of partial differential equation:

```
D[a[y,z],y]==D[b[x,z],z]
```

for which it is simple to get the solution by hand

> ```
> a -> D[g[z], z] y + h[z], b -> g[z] + f[z].
> ```

I also tried

```
DSolve[
  {D[a[x, y, z], x] == 0,
   D[b[x, y, z], y] == 0,
   D[a[x, y, z], y] == D[b[x, y, z], z]},
  {a[x,y,z], b[x,y,z]}, {x, y, z}]
```

Is there a way to go around that so that it can be solved by Mathematica?

In my actual work, the systems are much more complicated.

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for `PDE's` is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet. Maybe in next release MMA 11.3 they can be solved.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!